# Can you solve this integral without using partial fraction?

Tags: calculus, integration

It can be done by using partial fraction but it becomes complex. Is it possible to solve this in any other way?!

$$
\int \frac{dx}{(x-1)^2(x-2)^3}
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may avoid partial fraction with a little trick.

$$\int \frac{dx}{(x-1)^2(x-2)^3}=\int \frac{(x-1)dx}{(x-1)^3(x-2)^3} $$

Note that $$x-1 = (x-3/2) +1/2 = u+1/2$$ while $$x-2 = (x-3/2) -1/2 =u-1/2$$ where $ u=(x-3/2).$

Substitute in the integral  to get $$ \int \frac{(x-1)dx}{(x-1)^3(x-2)^3} =\int \frac{(u+1/2)du}{(u^2-1/4)^3}=\int \frac{udu}{(u^2-1/4)^3}+\int \frac{(1/2)du}{(u^2-1/4)^3} $$

These integrals do not require partial fractions.

Comment: In essence, $2u=x-1+x-2$

Comment: Correct, that is what I had in mind.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee but how to evaluate $\int \frac{(1/2)du}{(u^2-1/4)^3}$ without partial fraction?

Comment: $x=(1/2)sec (t)$

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

Write the numerator as $$((x+2)-(x+1))^3$$

Then $x+1=x+2-1$ and $x+2=x+1+1$

Alternatively use integration by parts

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{d\dfrac1{(x-1)^m(x-2)^n}}{dx}$$ $$=-\dfrac m{(x-1)^{m+1}(x-2)^n}-\dfrac n{(x-1)^m(x-2)^{n+1}}$$

Integrate both sides with respect to $x$

$$mI(m+1,n)=-nI(m,n+1)-\dfrac1{(x-1)^m(x-2)^n}$$

where $\displaystyle I(m,n)=\int\dfrac{dx}{(x-1)^m(x-2)^n}$

Start with $m+1=2,n=3$

Answer (score -3):

If $\frac{1}{(x-1)^2(x-2)^3}=\frac{a_1}{(x-1)}+\frac{a_2}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{b_1}{(x-2)}+\frac{b_2}{(x-2)^2}+\frac{b_3}{(x-2)^3}$

1. $b_3$ can be determined by multiplying the equation by $(x-2)^3$ and evaluating at $x=2$. You get that $\frac{1}{(2-1)^2}=b_3$.
2. $b_2$ can be determined by multiplying the equation by $(x-2)^3$, taking derivative, evaluating at $x=2$, and dividing by $1$. You get $-2\frac{1}{(2-1)^3}\cdot \frac{1}{1}=b_2$.
3. Finally, $b_1$ can be determined by multiplying the equation by $(x-2)^3$ taking two derivatives, evaluating at $x=2$, and dividing by $2\cdot 1$. You get $(-3)(-2)\frac{1}{(2-1)^4}\cdot\frac{1}{2\cdot 1}=b_1$.

$a_2$ and $a_1$ can be found in the same way as $b_3$ and $b_2$, respectively, but using $x-1$ and $x=1$ instead of $x-2$ and $x=2$.

The truth is that the partial fraction decomposition in cases like this can be computed easily, you can probably do it in your mind. These steps work for all rational functions. But in the case of only two or one irreducible factors in the denominator the step of taking derivative is simple enough to be able to do mentally.

To understand why it works you do need to write those steps down.

Comment: @Leucippus This gives what they need to know and don't know. Anything else matters nothing to me.